# Совмещение анимаций

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, анимация, css-animation

Есть две анимации движение и левитация.

```
@keyframes moveframe1{
  0% {
  transform:  translateX(0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
100% {
 transform:  translateX(2000px)  rotate(360deg) ;
  }
}

@keyframes levitate1 {
  0%,
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px);
      transform: translateY(-7px)
  }
  50% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
      transform: translateY(0)
  }
}


.emoji__item:nth-child(1){
    animation: moveframe1 0.8s forwards;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   animation-delay: 1s;
   position: relative;
   left: -2000px;
}
```

Как сделать что бы после окончания движения, продолжилась бесконечная левитация?

Answer (score 0):

в свойства анимация попробуй написать infinite. For ex.  animation: name linear infinite 2s; если получится то уже там можешь играться с процентамыб чтобы все выглядело нормально )

Answer (score 0):

Эти две анимации надо дать разным блокам. И с разными задержками:

Вот пример:

```html
<style>
 @keyframes moveframe1{
   0% {
   transform:  translateX(0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
   }
 100% {
  transform:  translateX(2000px)  rotate(360deg) ;
   }
 }

 @keyframes levitate1 {
   0%,
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px);
    transform: translateY(-7px)
   }
   50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
   }
 }


 .emoji__item{
  animation: moveframe1 0.8s forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    position: relative;
    left: -2000px;
 }
 
 .emoji__item>li{
  animation: levitate1 0.8s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
 }
 
</style>
<ul class="emoji__item">
 <li>sdfdsf</li>
</ul>
```

Первую анимацию дал элементу `ul` с задержкой 1 секунду и временем анимации 0,8 секунд, А вторую анимацию дал элементу `li` с задержкой началом анимации в 1,8 секунд, что бы она начинала после завершения первой анимации.